# Sum in R based on a date range and another condition?

Tags: r, sum, data.table, rolling-computation

I am working on a dataframe of baseball data called mlb_team_logs. A random sample lies below.

```
       Date    Team season AB PA  H  X1B X2B X3B HR R RBI BB IBB SO HBP SF SH GDP
1   2015-04-06  ARI   2015 34 39  9   7   1   1  0 4   4  3   0  6   2  0  0   2
2   2015-04-07  ARI   2015 31 36  8   4   1   1  2 7   7  5   0  7   0  0  0   1
3   2015-04-08  ARI   2015 32 35  5   3   2   0  0 2   1  2   0  7   1  0  0   0
4   2015-04-10  ARI   2015 35 38  7   6   0   0  1 4   4  3   0 10   0  0  0   0
5   2015-04-11  ARI   2015 32 35 10   9   0   0  1 6   6  3   0  7   0  0  0   1
6   2015-04-12  ARI   2015 36 38 10   7   3   0  0 4   4  1   0 11   0  0  1   1
7   2015-04-13  ARI   2015 39 44 12   8   3   1  0 8   7  4   0 11   0  0  1   0
8   2015-04-14  ARI   2015 28 32  3   1   2   0  0 1   1  3   0  4   1  0  0   2
9   2015-04-15  ARI   2015 33 34  9   7   1   0  1 2   2  1   0  8   0  0  0   1
10  2015-04-16  ARI   2015 47 51 11   6   2   0  3 7   7  3   1  8   1  0  0   0
240 2015-07-03  ATL   2015 30 32  7   4   1   0  2 2   2  2   0  6   0  0  0   1
241 2015-07-04  ATL   2015 34 40 10   6   3   0  1 9   9  5   0  5   0  0  1   0
242 2015-07-05  ATL   2015 35 37  7   6   1   0  0 0   0  1   0 10   1  0  0   1
243 2015-07-06  ATL   2015 40 44 15  10   4   0  1 5   5  3   0  7   0  0  1   1
244 2015-07-07  ATL   2015 34 37 10   7   1   1  1 4   4  2   0  4   0  0  1   1
245 2015-07-08  ATL   2015 31 38  7   4   1   0  2 5   5  5   1  7   0  0  2   1
246 2015-07-09  ATL   2015 34 37 10   8   2   0  0 3   3  1   0  9   0  1  1   2
247 2015-07-10  ATL   2015 32 35  8   7   0   0  1 3   3  2   0  5   1  0  0   2
248 2015-07-11  ATL   2015 33 38  6   3   1   0  2 2   2  5   1  8   0  0  0   0
249 2015-07-12  ATL   2015 34 41  8   6   2   0  0 3   3  7   1 10   0  0  0   1
250 2015-07-17  ATL   2015 30 36  7   4   3   0  0 4   4  5   1  7   0  0  0   0
```

In total, the df has 43 total columns. My objective is to sum columns 4 (AB) to 43 on two criteria:

1. the team
2. the date is within 7 days of the entry in "Date" (ie Date - 7 to Date - 1)

Eventually, I would like these columns to be appended to mlb_team_logs as l7_AB, l7_PA, etc (but I know how to do that if the output will be a new dataframe). Any help is appreciated!

*EDIT* I altered the sample to allow for more easily tested results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a `data.table` non-equi join here.  The idea would be to create a lower date bound (below, I've  named this `date_lb`), and then join the table on itself, matching on `Team = Team`, `Date < Date`,  and `Date >= date_lb`. Then use `lapply` with `.SDcols` to sum the columns of interest.

1. load library and set your frame to data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mlb_team_logs)
```

2. Identify the columns you want to sum, in a character vector (change to `4:43` in your full dataset)

```
sum_cols = names(mlb_team_logs)[4:19]
```

3. Add a lower bound on date

```
df[, date_lb := Date-7]
```

4. Join the table on itself, and use `lapply(.SD, sum)` on the columns of interest

```
result = mlb_team_logs[mlb_team_logs[, .(Team, Date, date_lb)], on=.(Team, Date<Date, Date>=date_lb)] %>% 
  .[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(Date,Team), .SDcols = sumcols ]
```

5. Set the new names (inplace, using `setnames()`)

```
setnames(result, old=sumcols, new=paste0("I7_",sumcols))
```

Output:

```
          Date   Team I7_AB I7_PA  I7_H I7_X1B I7_X2B I7_X3B I7_HR  I7_R I7_RBI I7_BB I7_IBB I7_SO I7_HBP I7_SF I7_SH I7_GDP
        <IDat> <char> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1: 2015-04-06    ARI    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA
 2: 2015-04-07    ARI    34    39     9      7      1      1     0     4      4     3      0     6      2     0     0      2
 3: 2015-04-08    ARI    65    75    17     11      2      2     2    11     11     8      0    13      2     0     0      3
 4: 2015-04-10    ARI    97   110    22     14      4      2     2    13     12    10      0    20      3     0     0      3
 5: 2015-04-11    ARI   132   148    29     20      4      2     3    17     16    13      0    30      3     0     0      3
 6: 2015-04-12    ARI   164   183    39     29      4      2     4    23     22    16      0    37      3     0     0      4
 7: 2015-04-13    ARI   200   221    49     36      7      2     4    27     26    17      0    48      3     0     1      5
 8: 2015-04-14    ARI   205   226    52     37      9      2     4    31     29    18      0    53      1     0     2      3
 9: 2015-04-15    ARI   202   222    47     34     10      1     2    25     23    16      0    50      2     0     2      4
10: 2015-04-16    ARI   203   221    51     38      9      1     3    25     24    15      0    51      1     0     2      5
11: 2015-07-03    ATL    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA
12: 2015-07-04    ATL    30    32     7      4      1      0     2     2      2     2      0     6      0     0     0      1
13: 2015-07-05    ATL    64    72    17     10      4      0     3    11     11     7      0    11      0     0     1      1
14: 2015-07-06    ATL    99   109    24     16      5      0     3    11     11     8      0    21      1     0     1      2
15: 2015-07-07    ATL   139   153    39     26      9      0     4    16     16    11      0    28      1     0     2      3
16: 2015-07-08    ATL   173   190    49     33     10      1     5    20     20    13      0    32      1     0     3      4
17: 2015-07-09    ATL   204   228    56     37     11      1     7    25     25    18      1    39      1     0     5      5
18: 2015-07-10    ATL   238   265    66     45     13      1     7    28     28    19      1    48      1     1     6      7
19: 2015-07-11    ATL   240   268    67     48     12      1     6    29     29    19      1    47      2     1     6      8
20: 2015-07-12    ATL   239   266    63     45     10      1     7    22     22    19      2    50      2     1     5      8
21: 2015-07-17    ATL    99   114    22     16      3      0     3     8      8    14      2    23      1     0     0      3
          Date   Team I7_AB I7_PA  I7_H I7_X1B I7_X2B I7_X3B I7_HR  I7_R I7_RBI I7_BB I7_IBB I7_SO I7_HBP I7_SF I7_SH I7_GDP
```

Comment: Thanks! What would be the adjustment here if I didn't want to include the listed date? I want to go only up until date-1

Comment: perhaps just change the join condition to `on=.(Team, Date<Date, Date>=date_lb)`?   It might also help with testing if you added some data in the OP that has relevant team/dates that will be added together.. (i.e. your random sample contains none). You can see I tried to test my solution, but didn't spend any time really creating a dataset that could look more closely at the solution

Comment: I updated the response so that the new join condition is used, and the new data you provided is also used. Note that the resulting data for the first row for each team in this example data is NA, because there are no rows for that team that within Date-1 and Date-7 of Date.